# Rspec won't let me set return value for "any?" method with stubs or should_receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Ok so I have been searching for days to fix this bug and I just can't seem to find an answer. I am trying to test my rails app with rspec and specifically doing controller testing right now.

In my controller I have the method

```
def update

  changes = @match_preference.changes

  ...

  if changes.values.collect(&:first).any?(&:nil?)
    flash[:notice] = 'Hello'
  end

  ...

end
```

and in my testing file I have this

```
before :each do 
  @match_preference = FactoryGirl.create :match_preference
end

it "should do something on first change" do
  # Line I have been changing a lot
  @match_preference.changes.values.collect.stubs(:any?).returns(true)
  post :update
  flash.should_not be_nil
end
```

I have also tried replacing that line with stub_chain and many other possible answers. I have found the problem to be with the function any? When I remove that function, I can change the return value of collect and it always works. Why won't any? allow me to set a return value?

I know the problem isn't with @match_preferences because I use it else where in the testing and it works.

I don't get any errors from this code, it just doesn't seem to correctly change the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values.collect` is going to return a new hash, which you are then stubbing. This isn't going to be the same hash that your controller processes.

Additionally, your `@match_preference` variable won't be the same as what's in your controller - your controller is going to perform a find and assign, so you need to either stub the find, or use `MatchPreference.any_instance`.

Since you're testing the result of ActiveModel::Dirty's `#changes`, which returns a hash, just stub `changes` to return a populated hash:

```
let(:match_preference) { FactoryGirl.create :match_preference }

it "should do something on first change" do
  MatchPreference.any_instance.stub(:changes).and_return({:bogus => [nil, "new"]})

  post :update
  flash.should_not be_nil
end
```

Or you can just stub your finder:

```
let(:match_preference) { FactoryGirl.create :match_preference }

it "should do something on first change" do
  match_preference.some_attribute = "new value"
  MatchPreference.stub(:find).and_return(match_preference)

  post :update
  flash.should_not be_nil
end
```

However, you can just stub `changed?` rather than looking at the values themselves:

Comment: hmm it seems to be having a problem with the &:first argument now. I am getting the error message: `Failure/Error: post :update
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'first' for true:TrueClass`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that each time you call the `collect` method, a new object is created, so stubbing one result of `collect` does nothing to the object that is return by the next call of that method. You should use [`stub_chain`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/docs/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods) instead (stubbing the method chain on your ActiveRecord object).

Note that you should work with the same ActiveRecord object that your controller retrieves, one possibility to ensure this is to stub the corresponding query call made by your controller action. Another possibility would be stubbing the method chain on [`any_instance`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class) of the ActiveRecord class.